# RSpec tests fails with subdomain path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, subdomain

I can't provide path for RSpec with subdomain. 
The testing path should be `api.example.com/public/v1/regions/origin?title=indm`

But I don't know how to provide such path for RSpec. How to path subdomain `api` to this relative path?

```
let(:api_path) { 'public/v1/regions/origin?title=indm' }
```

**log**

```
1) Regions Public API GET /v1/regions/origin?title=? returns 200 status code
     Failure/Error: get api_path
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/public/v1/regions/origin"
     # ./spec/api/public/v1/regions_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**routes.rb**

```
  namespace :api, path: '', constraints: {subdomain: 'api'} do
    namespace :public, defaults: { format: :json } do
      namespace :v1 do
        resources :regions do
          get :origin, on: :collection
          get :destination, on: :collection
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the really great way to solve this problem, but I did it using `pow` server with Anvil.
I have installed Anvil and run server with domain `orca.dev`. After this I reconfigured my RSpec testing routes.

**spec_helper.rb**

```
def get_api_path path, *args
  get "http://api.orca.dev#{path}", *args
end
```

**regions_spec.rb**

```
before do
  get_api_path '/public/v1/regions/origin?title=indm'
end
```

And now tests are working!